# How do you get all the table data between each other by using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to get table data from each other but there is no tag to speared.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = ['http://lotto.auzonet.com/biglotto/list_' + str(i + 1) + '_all.html' for i in range(2003, 2016)]

for link in source:
visit_request = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
visit_response = visit_request.read()
visit_soup = BeautifulSoup(visit_response, 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')

for ultag in visit_soup.find_all('td', {'class' : 'history_view'}):
    for table in ultag.find_all('table', {'class' : 'history_view_table'}):  
#table資料 ......
```

This is what I want[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the text inside second tr inside the *history_view_table*, *select_one('table.history_view_table tr:nth-of-type(2)')* will grab the second *tr*, calling *.find_all(text=True)* on that will get you all the text and we filter newlines etc.. with *if s.strip()*:

```
data =  [s.strip() for s in visit_soup.select_one('table.history_view_table tr:nth-of-type(2)').find_all(text=True) if s.strip()]
```

That should give you what you want:

```
In [1]: import urllib.request

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: visit_request = urllib.request.urlopen("http://lotto.auzonet.com/biglotto/list_2004_all.html")

In [4]: visit_response = visit_request.read()

In [5]: visit_soup = BeautifulSoup(visit_response, 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')

In [6]: [s.strip() for s in visit_soup.select_one('table.history_view_table tr:nth-of-type(2)').find_all(text=True)
   ...:        if s.strip()]
Out[6]: 
['093104',
 '2004-12-30',
 '(星期四)',
 '落球順序：',
 '03',
 '18',
 '33',
 '34',
 '43',
 '49',
 '大小順序：',
 '03',
 '18',
 '33',
 '34',
 '43',
 '49',
 '02',
 '$282,609,200']
```

That includes *'$282,609,200'* which you don't have highlighted in your image but it is before the next table so i presume that is an oversight.

Comment: Sorry! Your idea will be get only one record, but in my case I have to get all the data from table.history_view below, maybe I should't use select_one. The data like ['093104', '2004-12-30', '(星期四)', '落球順序：', '03', '18', '33', '34', '43', '49', '大小順序：', '03', '18', '33', '34', '43', '49', '02', '$282,609,200']
['093103', '2004-12-27', '(星期一)', '落球順序：', '01', '08', '16', '22', '24', '30', '大小順序：','01', '08', '16', '22', '24', '30', '14', '$534,870,700']

Comment: By the way, why I visit to http://www.powerball.com/ when I use prettify() I can see number but when I use find_all('table', {'align' : 'center'}) all the number will be hidden?